# Implementing WCF services for nopCommerce

Tags: wcf, nopcommerce

I been following/studying nopCommerce for a while now. Looking at this project am picking up few of its implementation techniques in my sample project utilizing Adventureworks DB. excluding plugin architecture from this project How can i implement WCF services on top of Nop.Services projects utilizing dependency injection and IOC containers.

Can anyone help me driving in right path?

Comment: im looking for the same, any result so far?

Comment: Hi, any solution???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

I created WCF service under a new folder in nop structure.

then in wcf web.config I have added this config below

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="NopConfig" type="Nop.Core.Configuration.NopConfig, Nop.Core, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <NopConfig>
    <DynamicDiscovery Enabled="true" />
    <Engine Type="" />
    <Themes basePath="~/Themes/" />
  </NopConfig>
```

(but make sure you have added config section node on the top of the other configuration nodes)

Copy Settings.txt and InstalledPlugins.txt files into WCF/AppData folder

then in svc file I have added a private IProductService variable and  constructor that calls using EngineContext and assign the variable which is like below. this will register the services

```
    private readonly IProductService _productService;


    public ProductWS() //servie constructorı
    {
        this._productService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IProductService>();

    }
```

create your domains in wcf and assign them with [DataContract] and [DataMember]

Hope it helps

Comment: This has happened twice. I have answered a question and my own answer helped me years later. :)) This is like a universal rule. Helping others is helping you.